# How to access elements of a dynamic object in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dynamic object from snapshot which looks like ;

```
 {allfruits: fruitInfo{fruitname: orange, fruitcolor: orange, 
 fruitquantity: 2, 
  fruitunit: kg}}
```

This is the code;

```
body: FutureBuilder(
    future: fruitList(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
     var fruit=snapshot.data;

     return ListView(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),

       children: [
         TextFormField(initialValue: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email,style:TextStyle(fontWeight: 
        
         Text(fruit,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18)),
```

how can i access individual elements from this like fruitcolor or fruitquantity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deserialize it.. convert the dynamic object into something like model first, then access all its members through that model.

example

```dart
class Person {
    final int? name;

    Person({this.name});

    factory Person.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
        return Person(
            name: map['name'],
        );
    }
}

void main() {
    final dynamicDataOrMap = {'name': 'john wick'}
    final person = Person.fromMap(dynamicDataOrMap);
    
    print(person.name);
}
```